# Access Denied when creating CloudFront invalidation with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I'm using the AWS CLI to create a CloudFront distribution in a script:

```
aws configure set preview.cloudfront true
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ABCD1234 --paths '/*'
```

I have a policy set up with this statement:

```
{
    "Sid": "xxx",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:cloudfront::xxx:distribution/ABCD1234"
    ]
}
```

The policy is attached to the user that is running the command. However, I still get this error:

> A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the CreateInvalidation operation: User: arn:aws:iam::xxx:user/yyy is not authorized to perform: cloudfront:CreateInvalidation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that CloudFront can't work with a policy that specifies a resource. "Widening" the policy fixes the error.

[This support thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=244541) states:

> CloudFront does not support Resource-Level permissions for IAM.

It's also buried in the [documentation for CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cf-api-permissions-ref.html#required-permissions-invalidations):

```
Operation:             POST Invalidation (CreateInvalidation)
Required Permissions:  cloudfront:CreateInvalidation
Resources:             *
```

That means the policy needs to be:

```
{
    "Sid": "xxx",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "*"  <-- must be a wildcard
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just want to add a small convenience – if using a SAM template.yml:

          - Sid: "CloudfrontPolicy"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Action: 
              - "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
            Resource: '*'