# How to authorize IAM cloudfront distribution with aws cli?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am trying to put AWS CLI commands in my script to setup a CloudFront distribution, add the SSL certificate, and create Route 53 route to the S3 bucket.

When I try and run any 
`aws cloudfront create-distribution..` I get access denied:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateDistribution operation: User: arn:aws:iam::388628639254:user/MyUserName is not authorized to perform: cloudfront:CreateDistribution

I have tried the following suggestion: 
[Access Denied when creating CloudFront invalidation with AWS CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830990/access-denied-when-creating-cloudfront-invalidation-with-aws-cli)

All of my resources are set to `*`

I have also added the following polices to my IAM user:

- `CloudFrontFullAccess`
- `AdministratorAccess`
- `IAMUserChangePassword`
- `CloudFrontReadOnlyAccess`
- `AmazonRoute53FullAccess`
- `PowerUserAccess`

I am hoping to both grant permission to my account and figure out which command with the AWS CLI is required to:

```
- Create Cloudfront Distribution
With Settings:
  - Add Domain
  - Redirect to HTTP/HTTPS 
  - Add custom SSL Cert
- Create Route 53 Record set for CloudFront
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

> User: arn:aws:iam::388628639254:user/MyUserName is not authorized to perform: cloudfront:CreateDistribution

This means that the IAM User you are using to perform your commands has not been given sufficient permissions to create a CloudFront distribution.

Normally, this would be a matter of asking your administrators to grant you the necessary access, but you seem to be able to configure IAM yourself.

Also, `CloudFrontFullAccess` grants all CloudFront permissions, which would seem sufficient.

Therefore, it is quite possible that, when you are running these commands, you are not actually using the credentials you expected. The error message is showing the name of the user, so check that the permissions have been added to this user.

Next, try creating a CloudFront distribution **via the CloudFront management console** *using the same User*. This will test whether you do, indeed, have the necessary permissions. If that works, then there is no logical reason why it would fail via the CLI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You're right, the priveledges should be working. It turns out my local aws cli was using a different IAM user than it should have been. 
I have since added `--profile default` to my flag, however I am still having issues with setting the cloudfront configuration through the GUI